# Нестандартный вид вывода таблицы в php из MySql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mysqli

Доброго времени суток, прошу помощи,
ситуация такая:
есть таблица в MySql:
[image: таблица MySql]

задача: вывести ее на страницу в виде:
[image: Итоговый вид на странице php]

шапку таблицы создавал следующим образом:

```
<thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th> </th>
                          <?php  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Соединение не удалось: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
$sqltableclandate = "SELECT * FROM  `nametable` GROUP BY Date";
$sqltableclanResultdate = $mysqli->query($sqltableclandate);  
while($tableclandate = $sqltableclanResultdate->fetch_assoc()) 
{?>
                                <th><?php echo $tableclandate['Date'];?></th>
                                <? }?>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
```

А вот дальше затык....

Подскажите куда копать и где искать)

Забыл вчера добавить:
*Добавление: если за какую-то дату нет информации, то в ячейке должен быть 0 или Н/Д*

Добавление всего кода таблицы на данный момент:

```
<?php require_once("includes/connection_new.php"); ?>
<div class="content">
<div id="TableClan">    
    <h2>Статистика:</h2>
    <table class="tablesorter" id="myTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                <th>Дата</th>
<?php $query_dateclan = "SELECT * FROM `DBname`.`stats` GROUP BY Date";
if($resultclandate = $mysqli->query($query_dateclan)){
        $rowclandate=$resultclandate->fetch_assoc();
        $kol_rowsclandate = $resultclandate->num_rows;
        for($i=0; $i<$kol_rowsclandate; $i++){?>
        <th> <? echo $rowclandate['Date']; ?> </th>
        <? }}?>


                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
<tr>
<td><? echo $rowclandate['name'] ?></td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
                        </table>
  </div>


<!-- тело любых страниц.php -->
</div>
```

вид базы:
таблица: stat (как видно name5 появился позже)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `GROUP_CONCAT()`, которая позволяет вывести списки каждой из групп, получаемых `GROUP BY`. Обычно в `GROUP_CONCAT()` передают имя столбца, но тут потребуется два значения - дата и `gold`. Их можно объединить при помощи `CONCAT()` каким-нибудь уникальным разделителем, например, решеткой.

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(data, "#", gold)) AS data_gold
FROM
  gold
GROUP BY
  name
+-------------------------------------------+
| data_gold                                 |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 2016-08-27#10,2016-08-28#15,2016-08-29#20 |
| 2016-08-27#20,2016-08-28#25,2016-08-29#30 |
| 2016-08-27#30,2016-08-28#35,2016-08-29#40 |
| 2016-08-27#40,2016-08-28#45,2016-08-29#50 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

В PHP-коде можно сначала разбить строку по запятой (например, функцией `explode()`), а потом каждый элемент полученного массива еще раз разбить по #. `GROUP_CONCAT` допускает сортировку, а по полученной дате вы всегда сможете определить к какой ячейке должен относиться текущей элемент.

Для формирования результирующей таблицы можно воспользоваться следующим PHP-кодом:

```
<?php
try {
  $pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
    'root',
    '',
    array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

  function parse_gold($str) {
    $elements = explode(',', $str);
    $arr = array();
    foreach($elements as $el)  {
      list($date, $gold) = explode('#', $el);
      $arr[$date] = $gold;
    }
    return $arr;
  }

  $query = "SELECT
              name,
              GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(data, '#', gold)) AS data_gold
            FROM
              gold
            GROUP BY
              name";
  $usr = $pdo->query($query);

  $users = array();
  while($user = $usr->fetch()) {
    $users[$user['name']] = parse_gold($user['data_gold']);
  }
  $dates = array();
  foreach($users as $user) {
    $dates += array_keys($user);
  }
  echo '<table border="1">';
  // Шапка
  echo '<tr><td>Имя</td>';
  foreach($dates as $date) {
    echo "<td>$date</td>";
  }
  echo '</tr>';
  // Содержимое таблицы
  foreach($users as $name => $golds) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>$name</td>";
    foreach($dates as $date) {
      if(array_key_exists($date, $golds)) {
        echo "<td>{$golds[$date]}</td>";
      } else {
        echo "<td>-</td>";
      }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: не могли бы Вы привести пример данной разбивки касательно моего случая, к сожалению моих знаний не хватает, чтобы понять без примера(

Comment: @Cheshire дополнил ответ.

Comment: к сожалению при выполнении ругается на 7 строку Вашего кода: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' "

Comment: @Cheshire вероятно у вас не самая свежая версия PHP, которая не работает с новым синтаксисом массивов. Поправил ответ, задействовав старый синтаксис.

Comment: все заработало, только в запросе после `FROM` название таблицы: `test`. Спасибо огромное, можете подсказать, что почитать на эту тему?

Comment: По MySQL давно свежей литературы не выходило, затрудняюсь посоветовать что актульное, кроме разве что документации, читайте все до чего дотянетесь :)

Answer (score 1):

вытяни данные с базы и сохрани в массив, а дальше через обычный foreach строишь таблицу
это пример, если не знаешь как, кидай весь файл помогу

```
<?php foreach ($category as $cat): ?>
      <tr>
          <td><?php echo $cat['id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $cat['name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $cat['sort_order']; ?></td>
      </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Какой именно файл кидать, полный код или вид базы?

Comment: все что есть кидай

Comment: добавил в главное сообщение